# Gitlab CI/CD deploy to aws via aws-azure-cli authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-iam, aws-cli

When deploying to AWS from gitlab-ci.yml file, you usually use aws-cli commands as scripts. At my current workplace, before I can use the aws-cli normally, I have to login via aws-azure-cli, authenticate via 2FA, then my workstation is given a secret key than expires after 8 hours.

Gitlab has CI/CD variables where I would usually put the AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY, but I can't create IAM role to get these. So I can't use aws-cli commands in the script, which means I can't deploy.

Is there anyway to authenticate Gitlab other than this? I can reach out to our cloud services team, but that will take a week.

Comment: Posted an answer, how did it go? did it worked?

Answer (score 0):

> You can configure OpenID to retrieve temporary credentials from AWS without needing to store secrets.

In my view it's actually a best practice too, to use OopenID roles instead of storing actual credentials.

- Add the identity provider for GitLab in AWS
- Configure the role and trust
- Retrieve a temporary credential

follow this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/aws/ or a more detailed version https://oblcc.com/blog/configure-openid-connect-for-gitlab-and-aws/